# Which database system should I use?

Tags: database, vb.net

I have been doing quite a bit of research trying to figure out which database system would best suite my needs, but I need a little guidance. I am writing a `VB.Net program` that keeps track of inventory, to be used by small businesses. I will be using a client server type model, with 1 computer on the network acting as a server, the rest clients. The avg number of client computers will probably be 2-5 or so. The most would be 10-15. Right now I am using an Access DB stored on a network Hard drive, but that way is slower and not very stable. Access was the first DB for me to learn how to program with so that is why I am using it now, but I know I need to change that going forward.

Requirements:

- I want the installation process to be easy and simple because these businesses will have no IT Dept. Database server needs to be installed along with program installation.
- Items and customers will be continuously added, so database size limits concerns me a little bit, as I don't want to have problems later on when the database size gets maxed out.

Here is what I have gathered about the following DB types:

**Access:** What I use now. file based db. not intended for multiple users using 1 DB.

**MySQL:** Open source but seems distributing with program requires licensing, so this is out. I wish this was an option, but I need free.

**SQL Server EXPRESS 2005/2008**: No licensing, also 2008 R2 has a 10gb limit. I am leaning towards this for now. Seems to be easiest integration with VB.Net & Visual Studio. Prerequisites are available in Visual Studio (for SQL Server 2005) so SQL server will get installed during program installation.

**SQL Server CE:** file based db. maybe not the best choice for client/server setup? Might not be any better than how I use Access now. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Firebird:** I see other programs are using it in a client/server type setup, but it looks like a file based db? Also looks like support for vb.net + firebird is scarce, which scares me. No limits though, which would be awesome.

I've done tons of research, but I still don't know which is best for my situation.

Comment: That said, if you're using a client-server .NET app, use SQL Server. 2012, not 2005, why would you even use a release that's close to a decade old? And if your clients don't have an IT department, hosting their own server software seems like a wrongheaded approach to begin with. I'd consider making your app a hosted service instead.

Comment: I'm also confused about why the database server has to be free. Aren't you getting paid for this? Just include the licence price for the components you require into what you're billing. That said, Postgres is also an option, but not exactly easy to install. SQL Server CE is an option if by client-server you mean that you're also writing a server component for your app, i.e. your clients aren't directly opening connections to the database. The fact that it's file-based doesn't matter if it's only the one server process accessing it. Also, 10GB for "business" data is plenty.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. just an Update for anybody that cares - I settled on SQL Server Express 2008 R2. I noticed another inventory program on the market used this so thought I'd give it a try. Turns out, it is a NIGHTMARE to install. I created an installer script to install SQL Server without any input from the user (this needs to be simple.). It was just too complicated and finicky though, as the 5 computers with different OS I tried to install it on, only 2 actually worked. Random errors with the other 3. So I decided to check out PostgreSQL and so far I am very pleased. Seems much simpler.

Comment: I didn't want to babysit every installation so thats why I am turned off by SQL Server express. Postgre so far seems to just work. Install via command line in unattended mode if not already installed > enable remote connection by editing config file > create database if not detected > add port 5432 firewall exception > and wa-la, postgre server installed and ready to roll.

Comment: Just stumbled upon my old question from 7 years ago. I'd add this as an answer but it won't let me since this is closed. I went with Postgres, and it works perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. The install process is totally automated so no issues with users installing my app and postgres along with it. It is free which is good because why pay for something when you can have free if the quality is good. So for the client/server model I was looking for, Postgres has been a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the approach you are taking is incorrect. You're asking your customers to install a RDBMS system and software when they don't have an IT department. Who is going to maintain this?

If this were me, I'd propose a hosted model web app perhaps using Windows Azure where you have a single centralized database for all your clients (create a multi-tenant database) and Microsoft handles all the infrastructure hassles. Or go with some third-part hosting solution that supports SQL Server 2012 (why consider 2005 or 2008?). Either would be better, IMO, than what you're proposing. And I believe it would be considerably easier to maintain and serve all your clients in this type of set up.